# Dyslexia and the GRE

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, statement-of-purpose, gre

I am applying to math graduate schools this year. Hence, I had to take the General GRE and Math Subject GRE. Only recently has it come to my attention that I could have applied for 1.5 or 2 times more time on these tests due to my Dyslexia. I had no idea that was the case so I did not do so. Therefore I missed out on a huge opportunity to increase my scores. Is there any way I can salvage this situation? Somehow alert admissions that I have trouble working under big time constraints and reading fast and that I did not utilize the accommodations?  It never occurred to me to apply for accommodation as time was never a problem in college.

In case it is relevant:

Math subject 72 procentile

Quant 165

Verbal 155

I was considering mentioning it in my personal statement, or something like that.

Any advice appreciated, I feel like that was a horrible blunder on my part that could have cost me getting into a great school.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to retake the GRE under fairer conditions. If you have already sent out the current scores, you can also update your application to mention the conditions under which you took the test the first time. Currently, however, if you have taken the test multiple times, as many do, you can decide which scores are to be sent.

But somewhere in your application materials I suspect that you also address your dyslexia and talk about why it isn't a hinderance to your success.

I'll note, as I have in answers to other questions, that admissions is almost never just a numbers game and individuals are examined for evidence that predicts success in future study. Some places that are overwhelmed with applications may need to reduce the number of applicants considered to a reasonable number, but normally, you need to present an application that shows both the background and the work ethic to succeed.

If you have any negative markers in your application then they need to be explained. Hopefully, the system is sensible enough that you can amend an application that requires it. But if you haven't yet applied, make sure that your materials honestly explain things that might be questioned.

Comment: thank you for the input. However, retaking the subject test is out of the question as all the dates have passed. That is why I would like to know if there is anything else I can do, other than retaking it.

Comment: Other than mentioning it to places you apply, all I can think of is contacting ETS for advice. Since admissions doesn't depend on single factors, you can probably make a case with most institutions.

Comment: So I should mention it in my personal statement? Is that what you mean by mentioning it to places I apply? Also thank you about mentioning emailing ETS, I will do that and see if they have any advice.

Comment: If possible, you could, perhaps, provide a footnote somewhere that mentions the issue. Somewhere that you are discussing your condition, noting that you took the GRE not realizing that accommodations can be made. I don't think it needs a long explanation. If it raises a question and if an interview is part of the process you can expand on it there as needed.